# Unit testing decorators in Python

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, decorator

I wrote the following decorator to be used in some Django views where I don't want the user to be logged in (like *register* and *forgot-password*):

```
def not_logged_in(view, redirect_url=None):
    def _wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                redirect_url or '/'
            )
        return view(*args, **kwargs)

    return _wrapper
```

Once I have it, I can easily write:

```
@not_logged_in
def register(request):
    ...
```

I have written unit tests for the views that are using it, and it is working without problems, but I'm wondering what would be the best way of unit testing the `not_logged_in` function alone?

Comment: Have you looked at the test for login_required? https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/tests/decorators.py

Comment: @dannyroa Thank you very much. I will do now. I'm pretty sure it will be a great reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you can easily mock the `request` object, then decorate a trivial function with your decorator and pass that request a parameter.

I also suppose that your `_wrapper` does not really have an unused `request` parameter?

Comment: You are correct. First of all, I was doing `def __wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` but then I added the `request` parameter manually, and forgot to modify the code here on SO :)